# Share GitHub Actions workflow within organization

Tags: github, github-actions

It seems like it's possible to create a `.github` repository within the organization and share workflows across my org.

The problem is, it seems like the `.github` repo must be *public*. What's the idea behind this? Why would I want to create a public repo for all my workflows within my organization?

I thought switching to GitHub Enterprise would help me on this matter, but it doesn't looks like it does.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like this is indeed the case.  its on the roadmap but no ETA exist https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/51

Comment: The reason behind it is that the token your action gets is scoped to the repo. making sure you don't get accidental access to other private repos in the org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/51

private repository for workflow templates is on the Roadmap but its indeed does not supported at the moment.

too bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to share your github action workflows privately. You can create a private repo and save your workflows as template.

https://medium.com/@er.singh.nitin/how-to-share-the-github-actions-workflow-in-an-organization-privately-c3bb3e0deb3

Answer (score 0):

This is now generally available for GitHub Enterprises

- https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-04-sharing-github-actions-within-your-enterprise-is-now-ga/
- https://docs.github.com/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-enterprise